# Clone maven repository (Archiva manager)

Tags: linux, maven, repository, clone, archiva

I have an maven repository (managed with Archiva) in my environment to use it for application development. Since it is a mirror of central repository, it has all dependencies I need for my application.
If I want to give the application sources to someone who doesn't have external connection, how can I clone my Archiva repository on its environment? Is there a way to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

simply copy the disk content from repositories directory